# How to access local variables in remote server using ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to access my local variable in remote server. Which command should I use.

Ex.
cmd:

```
SERVER 1
VAR=2
ssh unix-user@remote-server-name "bash abc.sh"
```

REMOTE SERVER:

```
cat abc.sh
echo $VAR
```

output should get `2`.

Comment: Use ```man ssh``` and look for ```SendEnv```.

Comment: @accdias : I tried using SendEnv but not able to achieve it

Comment: @Patils If something is not working then you should post your command, and the error message. How do you expect someone to help you without more information.

Comment: @Patils, read the answer on my 2nd comment. You need to configure the remote server with ```AcceptEnv``` as well.

Comment: VAR=5 ;


ssh -o SendEnv=VAR user@remote-hostname 'echo $VAR'


==> not getting any output @accdias any other command can you pls suggest here

Comment: In your example this might work: `source <(ssh unix-user@remote-server-name "cat abc.sh")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the variable directly on the remote side:

```
ssh unix-user@remote-server-name "export VAR=2; bash abc.sh"
```

Comment: I am getting variable (its a credentails) only in server1 which needs to be access in server2.

Comment: Environment variables are public! Don't publish credentials in environment variables.